# GA Reporting API v4 ga:users count not matching the UI

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4, google-analytics-sdk

The total number that was returned from the API is actually higher compared to what's being shown in the UI.

Screenshot attached shows Users total count is 5,275.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DEyB.jpg)

[image]

However, the API shows 6152 users in total.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJANs.jpg)

[image]

Any ideas on how to get valid users count?

Answer (score 1):

The report you are looking at on Google analytics is

Dimension

- Date

Metric

- users
- sessions
- pageviews

You have added `datehour` in your report the results of the report will not be the same unless the request is the same as the report you are looking at